# Undefined Error when applying materials to gltf object

Tags: three.js, gltf

I created a Three.js Scene where it loads a GLtf Object (.glb) inside a RGBELoader (for hdr Enviroment Texture Lighting )

I then give each Mesh inside this GLtf Object a new Material. Like this:

```
              gltfObject.traverse((ChildGLTF) => {

              ChildGLTF.children[0].material = MidMaterial;
              ChildGLTF.children[1].material = TopMaterial;
              ChildGLTF.children[2].material = BotMaterial;
              
            });
```

Now the strange thing is, I get an Error and at the same time the materials are applied like I want them to. So it actually works.

Still I want to get rid of that error or at least understand what is causing it.

Thats the Error:

```
script.js:77 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'material')
at script.js:77
at Mesh.traverse (three.module.js:6907)
at Group.traverse (three.module.js:6913)
at script.js:72
at GLTFLoader.js:175
at GLTFLoader.js:1989
```

So my best guess is, that there are more than one .material Attributes? But how can i specify, that I only want the material that is changeable..

Or is it, that 'gltfObject.traverse((ChildGLTF)' runs more than one time with ChildGLTF as an array? If so, "console.log( ChildGLTF[0] );" gives "undefined" ..

Here are the console logs

```
              console.log( ChildGLTF[0] ); //'undefined'
              console.log( ChildGLTF.children[0] ); //works fine
              console.log( ChildGLTF.children[0].material ); //'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'material')'
```

console.log( ChildGLTF.children[0] )

> ! Mesh {uuid: '3BE5076C-A90D-47B4-BE40-D1E77E4F4DEC', name: 'Cube', type: 'Mesh', parent: Group, children: Array(0), …}
> animations: []
> castShadow: false
> children: []
> frustumCulled: true
> geometry: BufferGeometry {uuid: 'EC8A35A7-1942-4556-9D93-6C3E25F4C77A', name: '', type: 'BufferGeometry', index: BufferAttribute, attributes: {…}, …}
> layers: Layers {mask: 1}
> material: MeshStandardMaterial {uuid: 'ACA40D34-B763-42DA-A956-3ABBAC901D37', name: '', type: 'MeshStandardMaterial', fog: true, blending: 1, …}
> matrix: Matrix4 {elements: Array(16)}
> matrixAutoUpdate: true
> matrixWorld: Matrix4 {elements: Array(16)}
> matrixWorldNeedsUpdate: false
> name: "Cube"
> parent: Group {uuid: '27EE9C8E-3B31-4483-8058-CA2DA42070FC', name: 'Scene', type: 'Group', parent: Scene, children: Array(3), …}
> position: Vector3 {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}
> quaternion: Quaternion {_x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 0, _w: 1, _onChangeCallback: ƒ}
> receiveShadow: false
> renderOrder: 0
> rotation: Euler {_x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 0, _order: 'XYZ', _onChangeCallback: ƒ}
> scale: Vector3 {x: 1, y: 1, z: 1}
> type: "Mesh"
> up: Vector3 {x: 0, y: 1, z: 0}
> userData: {name: 'Cube'}
> uuid: "3BE5076C-A90D-47B4-BE40-D1E77E4F4DEC"
> visible: true
> drawMode: (...)
> eulerOrder: (...)
> id: 40
> modelViewMatrix: Matrix4 {elements: Array(16)}
> normalMatrix: Matrix3 {elements: Array(9)}
> useQuaternion: (...)
> [[Prototype]]: Object3D

console.log( ChildGLTF.children[0].material );

> ! MeshStandardMaterial {uuid: 'FBA72EAB-93C3-4F92-B141-1BA011BB81FD', name: 'CubeMaterial', type: 'MeshStandardMaterial', fog: true, blending: 1, …}
> alphaMap: null
> alphaTest: 0
> aoMap: null
> aoMapIntensity: 1
> blendDst: 205
> blendDstAlpha: null
> blendEquation: 100
> blendEquationAlpha: null
> blendSrc: 204
> blendSrcAlpha: null
> blending: 1
> bumpMap: null
> bumpScale: 1
> clipIntersection: false
> clipShadows: false
> clippingPlanes: null
> color: Color {r: 0.011123105883598328, g: 0.004119289573282003, b: 0.8000000715255737}
> colorWrite: true
> defines: {STANDARD: ''}
> depthFunc: 3
> depthTest: true
> depthWrite: true
> displacementBias: 0
> displacementMap: null
> displacementScale: 1
> dithering: false
> emissive: Color {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0}
> emissiveIntensity: 1
> emissiveMap: null
> envMap: null
> envMapIntensity: 1
> flatShading: false
> fog: true
> lightMap: null
> lightMapIntensity: 1
> map: null
> metalness: 0
> metalnessMap: null
> morphNormals: false
> morphTargets: false
> name: "CubeMaterial"
> normalMap: null
> normalMapType: 0
> normalScale: Vector2 {x: 1, y: 1}
> opacity: 1
> polygonOffset: false
> polygonOffsetFactor: 0
> polygonOffsetUnits: 0
> precision: null
> premultipliedAlpha: false
> refractionRatio: 0.98
> roughness: 0.5
> roughnessMap: null
> shadowSide: null
> side: 2
> skinning: false
> stencilFail: 7680
> stencilFunc: 519
> stencilFuncMask: 255
> stencilRef: 0
> stencilWrite: false
> stencilWriteMask: 255
> stencilZFail: 7680
> stencilZPass: 7680
> toneMapped: true
> transparent: false
> type: "MeshStandardMaterial"
> userData: {}
> uuid: "FBA72EAB-93C3-4F92-B141-1BA011BB81FD"
> version: 0
> vertexColors: false
> vertexTangents: false
> visible: true
> wireframe: false
> wireframeLinecap: "round"
> wireframeLinejoin: "round"
> wireframeLinewidth: 1
> id: 7
> overdraw: (...)
> shading: (...)
> stencilMask: (...)
> wrapAround: (...)
> wrapRGB: (...)
> [[Prototype]]: Material

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.traverse(...)` is going to run that callback for every object within the model, and your code assumes each object has exactly three children. That's not possible, because the model would have to be infinitely deep, and when you eventually reach an object that doesn't have children, doing `.children[0].material` will throw these errors.

You'll want to check what `ChildGLTF`is, and *only* modify that one object during the loop.

```js
gltfObject.traverse((child) => {
  if (!child.isMesh) return;

  if (child.name === 'MyMidMeshName') { // change this name
    child.material = MidMaterial;
  } else if (child.name === 'MyTopMeshName') { // change this name
    // ...
  } else {
    // ...
  }
});
```